# Por que meu selectOnMenu do primefaces é renderizado de forma diferente?

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Por que meus componentes `selectOneMenu` do primefaces não é renderizado por inteiro?

**Componente normal do primefaces:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu componente renderizado :**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem do problema. Como alterar o css do prime?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tem algum css para esse select?

Comment: Rafael eu uso o bootstrap. Nele existem diversas configurações para o elemento `select`, mas inspecionando, o gerar a página o primefaces também importa seus css. Outro detalhe. Criei uma classe específica para modificar o  ´select`, ele muda cor, font mas o a seta continua sendo exibida pela metade.

Comment: Entendi, com certeza tem algum css interferindo, um dos problemas que sempre tenho é sobrescrever o css do primefaces, ele sempre da um trabalho. Inspecione o `select` e veja se o css do `bootstrap` está interferindo. E poste o código se puder para eu tentar ajuda-lo.

Comment: Rafael eu achei. Veja na imagem. Agora, como faço para alterar o css do primefaces? Veja que a class está numa `div` onde o elemento `select` é inserido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na sua página onde está seu `select`:

```
 <style type="text/css">
     .ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-trigger{
         width: 25px !important;
        /* coloque aqui as propriedades do css que deseja mudar com a tag !important */
     }
</style>
```

Com isso ele vai sobrescrever o css do primefaces. Basta usar as mesma classes do css que o primefaces e mudar qual propriedade você deseja.

Comment: Rafael funcionou.... obrigado!